# When the contraction of maximal ideals is an injective open mapping

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ and $B$ be two commutative rings with identity and let $f: A → B$ be a homomorphism of rings.
If $q$ is a prime ideal of $B$, $f^{-1}(q)$ is a prime ideal of $A$. Therefore we obtain a map
 $f' :  Spec(B) → Spec(A)$, where $f'(q) =f^{-1}(q)$.

Now is there any condition on $A$ or $B$ or $f$ such that 
 $f'(Max(B))\subseteq Max(A)$, $f'$ is injective and $f'$ is open mapping? (Spec(R) is the set of all prime ideals of $R$ and Max(R) is the set of all maximal ideals of $R$)

Answer (score 2):

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A$ and $B$ be finitely generated $k$-algebras. Let $f: A \to B$ be a homomorphism. I claim that if $\mathfrak{m} \subseteq B$ is a maximal ideal, then the pre image $\mathfrak{n}=f^{-1}(\mathfrak{m}) \subseteq A$ is a maximal ideal.

To see this, consider the induced map $g: A/\mathfrak{n} \to B/\mathfrak{m}$. Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal, $B/\mathfrak{m}$ is a finite extension of $k$. But $k$ is algebraically closed so $B/\mathfrak{m}=k$. Hence we have a sequence $k \to A \overset{g}\to k$. But $g$ is injective, so $A \cong k$, from which it follows that $\mathfrak{n}$ is maximal.

In other words, $maxSpec$ constitutes a functor from the category of finitely generated $k$-algebras to the category of locally ringed spaces, provided $k$ is algebraically closed.

If you want the map $f'$ to be injective, one sufficient condition is that $f:A \to B$ should be surjective. In this case, however, the map $f': maxSpec(B) \to maxSpec(A)$ is a closed embedding, so not open in general.

An example of an open embedding is the map induced by a localization map $p: A \to A_f$. This gives a homeomorphism $p': maxSpec(A_f) \to maxSpec(A)$ onto the distinguished open $D(f)$. However, not all open sets in $maxSpec(A)$ are affine (though they locally are). As an example of when an open set fails to be affine consider the punctured plane $\mathbb{A}^2-\{0\}$.

It is actually quite difficult to find morphisms of (affine) schemes that are topologically open, in general. Usually, the best we can say is that the image of $f'$ is locally closed, i.e. a finite union of intersections of an open set with a closed set (see Chevalley's theorem).

Comment: Dear leibnewtz , is $f' :maxSpec(B)→maxSpec(A)$ a closed embedding in general or in your example?

Comment: @Deroty The map $f': maxSpec(B) \to maxSpec(A)$ is not necessarily a closed embedding, unless the map $f: A \to B$ is surjective

Comment: Is the surjectivity  a necessary condition?

Comment: In general, a closed immersion of affine schemes $f: X \to Y$ is defined as a closed map $f$ such that the map $ f': \mathcal{O}_Y \to f_{*}\mathcal{O}_X$ is surjective. Geometrically this means that functions on $X$ can be extended to functions on $Y$. I'm not sure, however, if you can have a map that's topologically closed but not a closed immersion. I suspect it's possible, otherwise that wouldn't be in the definition

Comment: A finite (=integral of finite type) map $f:A\to B$  of rings induces a topologically  closed morphism of affine schemes which is  not a closed immersion in general. For example the inclusion $\mathbb C[T^2]\hookrightarrow \mathbb C[T]$ induces a ramified covering space of order two on the corresponding maximal spectra.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg That's a nice example. Though shouldn't you assume $f$ is not surjective? Isn't a surjection always integral and of finite type?

Comment: Dear leibnewtz, a finite map $f:A\to B$ **always** induces a topologically closed scheme morphism $f':Spec B\to Spec A$ , which restricts to a closed map of maximal spectra $res f':Specmax B\to Specmax A$  in the case that $A,B$ are finitely generated algebras over  a field.  If that finite map $f$  of finitely generated algebras happens to be surjective then the corresponding morphism will be a closed embedding, as you quite judiciously stated in your answer.

Comment: @Deroty In general the surgectivity is not necessary. For example let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity and $B=A[[x]]}$, the ring of all power series over $A$. Let $f:A\to B$ be the inclusion function. Thus it is not surjective but $f': Max(B)\to Max(A)$,( $f'(<m, x>)=m$, where m is any maximal ideal of $A$) is an open injective continuous function.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: @E.Rostami If by closed embedding you mean closed immersion than the map does have to be surjective. If you just mean a topologically closed embedding then it does not